# How do i access the camera memory buffer in ueye camera without is_ImageFile()?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a hard float system to do real time image processing using a ueye camera. For each snapshot, i have to save the image and then read it again to start with the image processing task. Is there a way i can copy image data in the camera memory directly to a buffer in my local memory without having to write it in a particular format (bmp/jpeg) and having to read it again? I am not using openCV. I have defined the image struct using openCV format but have removed all openCV dependencies and the code works fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239580/how-do-i-access-the-camera-memory-buffer-in-ueye-camera-without-is_imagefile()-?/) by [findnitai](https://answers.ros.org/users/27494/findnitai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at the existing packages for ueye cameras? If you can't use one of them directly, the source code may answer some of your questions.

- http://wiki.ros.org/ueye_cam
- http://wiki.ros.org/ueye

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2016-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0